# Can I create transparent buttons in Visual Studio 2005 with C#

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2005, user-interface, button, transparent

I have a user interface that requires placing some round buttons in a C# project with some data behind them. The buttons are System.Windows.Forms.buttons and I have used a GIF image with transparency to create them.  However, the transparent areas aren't transparent.  I've looked for references online but haven't found any suggestions for how to do this properly.  There's some mention of doing it in Visual Studio 2008 but I need to keep this project in 2005. Any help or suggestion is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty sure you need to use PNGs with WinForms to get image transparency. I know I've used them successfully.

EDIT: When I used the PNGs, I was overlaying them with the Image control onto the Form1.BackgroundImage; I wasn't using them in buttons.

I think your best bet is to switch from using a button control to using an image control. You might also try changing the button style to flat (I think it was flat, maybe one of the other styles) and seeing if you can get the effect you want that way.

Answer (score 1):

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Drawing;

public class TransparentControl : Control
{
    public TransparentControl()
    {
        SetStyle(ControlStyles.SupportsTransparentBackColor, true);
        SetStyle(ControlStyles.Opaque, true);
        SetStyle(ControlStyles.ResizeRedraw, true);
        this.BackColor = Color.Transparent;
    }

    protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs pevent)
    {
        Graphics g = pevent.Graphics;
        g.DrawRectangle(Pens.Black, this.ClientRectangle);
    }


    protected override void OnPaintBackground(PaintEventArgs pevent)
    {
        // don't call the base class
        //base.OnPaintBackground(pevent);
    }


    protected override CreateParams CreateParams
    {
        get
        {
            const int WS_EX_TRANSPARENT = 0x20;
            CreateParams cp = base.CreateParams;
            cp.ExStyle |= WS_EX_TRANSPARENT;
            return cp;
        }
    }

    // rest of class here...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
        Bitmap temp = new Bitmap(button1.Image);

        temp.MakeTransparent(Color.Black); //your transparent color, in this case black

        button1.Image = (Image) Logo;

        temp.Dispose();

        temp = null;
```

Answer (score 1):

Just set the Button's [FlatStyle property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.buttonbase.flatstyle.aspx) to "Flat"…and voilà!  I know this works with PNGs, but I haven't tested it with GIFs.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set BackColor property of a button to "Transparent".

Button1.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Transparent;

Answer (score 0):

create a class derived from button and put this code.

```
    protected override CreateParams CreateParams
    {
        get
        {
            const int WS_EX_TRANSPARENT = 0x20;
            CreateParams cp = base.CreateParams;
            cp.ExStyle |= WS_EX_TRANSPARENT;
            return cp;
        }
    }
```

and in create method

```
        SetStyle(ControlStyles.SupportsTransparentBackColor, true);
        SetStyle(ControlStyles.Opaque, true);
        this.BackColor = Color.Transparent;
```

Answer (score 0):

The following answer is verified in Visual Studio 2012 and works with backgroundImage format BMP, GIF, PNG as well as JPG; created by MS Paint.

To make your background visible through your button:

Go to the properties window of the button. Then change the FlatStyle and BackColor as shown in the image below:

[image: The FlatStyle is to be chosen as Flat]

[image: The color is to be chosen from Web Tab]

Note: The color is to be chosen from Web Tab and The FlatStyle is to be chosen as Flat.

But after this, the button will be transparent till mouse do not hover or it is selected or pressed. On that condition, it will be in some non-transparent color. If you want to make it always transparent, follow the following images and change the corresponding colors to transparent as before. The colors to be changed are: 'MouseOverBackColor' & 'MouseDownBackColor'.

[image]

[image]

Note: If you choose always transparent, as shown, there will be no change in the appearance of the button while it will be in action!

Hope it will help you.

Best of luck!