# C# Windows Form Application Transparent button

Tags: c#, button

I'm new to C#. I'd like to create an invisible button, but they are click-able in C# windows form application. Is there a way? I tried BackColor to Transparent, but that does not change the fact that it is transparent

Comment: Possible dupe of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1086621/drawing-a-transparent-button-in-c-sharp-winforms

Comment: The transparency for controls in windows is just now working (not supported)

Comment: Dont reinvent the wheel try this:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1086621/drawing-a-transparent-button-in-c-sharp-winforms

Comment: The label is not really transparent itself

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Its simple try this.

Click the button that you want to make transparent.
Select `FlatStyle` from Properties and set it to **popup**
Now change the `BackColor` property to `Transparent`.

This will make the button transparent.

However if you want to make it transparent over a `PictureBox` this method wont work..

It works only on normal backgrounds and background images.
Hope it works....

Comment: Wonderful! Best answer so far.

Comment: If you also want a transparent border, set the FlatStyle to "Flat" and then the FlatAppearance:BorderSize to 0 (zero).

Comment: Not Work now 2022 in VS 2022 XD

Answer (score 7):

```
buttonLink.FlatStyle = FlatStyle.Flat; 
buttonLink.BackColor = Color.Transparent;
buttonLink.FlatAppearance.MouseDownBackColor = Color.Transparent;
buttonLink.FlatAppearance.MouseOverBackColor = Color.Transparent;
```

Comment: Provide  a little context describing how it does what it does and perhaps a larger and better formatted code snippet. If you have a link to where you found this, please provide that as well.

Comment: Not Work now 2022 in VS 2022 XD

Answer (score 2):

The answers given just make the background color of the control you want to make transparent the same as the background color of its parent. It's not true transparency and windows forms doesn't support true transparency.

> Windows Forms controls do not support true transparency. The background of a
> transparent Windows Forms control is painted by its parent.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/winforms/controls/how-to-give-your-control-a-transparent-background?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8&redirectedfrom=MSDN

Comment: Even more pertinent note from that page: "The Button control doesn't support a transparent backcolor even when the BackColor property is set to Transparent."

Answer (score 1):

### Reference:

Original article and code can be found at:

### [Displaying a ToolTip when the Mouse Hovers Over a Disabled Control](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/32083/Displaying-a-ToolTip-when-the-Mouse-Hovers-Over-a)

#### @ CodeProject by [tetsushmz](http://www.codeproject.com/script/Membership/View.aspx?mid=4277306)

### Code:

```
public class TransparentSheet : ContainerControl
{
    public TransparentSheet()
    {
        // Disable painting the background.
        this.SetStyle(ControlStyles.Opaque, true);
        this.UpdateStyles();

        // Make sure to set the AutoScaleMode property to None
        // so that the location and size property don't automatically change
        // when placed in a form that has different font than this.
        this.AutoScaleMode = AutoScaleMode.None;

        // Tab stop on a transparent sheet makes no sense.
        this.TabStop = false;
    }

    private const short WS_EX_TRANSPARENT = 0x20;

    protected override CreateParams CreateParams
    {
        [SecurityPermission(SecurityAction.LinkDemand, UnmanagedCode = true)]
        get
        {
            CreateParams l_cp;
            l_cp = base.CreateParams;
            l_cp.ExStyle = (l_cp.ExStyle | WS_EX_TRANSPARENT);
            return l_cp;
        }
    }
}
```

### Explanation:

What you need to do is use the given control as an overlay on your disabled *TextBox* (that you mentioned in one of your comments). Sibscribe to the overlay control's *Click* event and you have yourself a click on a disabled control.

I strongly recommend against this approach and feel it is kind of a hack. You really should look for an alternative approach instead of having to use a disabled control with an overlay control on top of it.

Maybe a different UI or atleast wrap it up in a *UserControl* to isolate this messy logic.

Answer (score 0):

Setting the background property of the button to transparent will still leave a border.  If you want a completely transparent button, do one of 2 things:

Create a transparent panel and assign a method to the Click event

or preferably

Create a custom UserControl that is filled with only BackColor (set to transparent) and assign method to Click event.

```
public class Invisible_Button : UserControl
{
    protected override void OnMouseMove(MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnMouseMove(e);
        this.Cursor = Cursors.Hand;
    }
    protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnPaint(e);
        e.Graphics.FillRectangle(new SolidBrush(this.BackColor), 0, 0, this.Width, this.Height);
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Did you try `button.Visible = false`?
If all you want is to hide it, this will do the job.

Comment: That doesn't work if you want to do anything with the button control, such as clicking it.

Comment: Agreed, but it is unclear if he just wants to hide it until some event, or wants a transparent button over some other elements.

Comment: With that property, I couldnt click the button. So actually I want a click event for textbox (property: Enabled = false) so that when I click on it, it will return a value. But since that it cant do that, I have to come up with an invisible button/label, but clickable