# Visual C++ Transparent BackColor of Button

Tags: c++, image, button, colors, transparent

I know this question has been already asked quite some times, but i would like to specify it. I got an image, which displays a circle blue X and I would like to make my own exit button in a Windows application form.

To do that, i added a button in the form and loaded the image on the button. However, the backcolor of the button ruins the image as it is grey. So i have tried:

```
private: System::Void button1_Paint(System::Object^  sender, 
System::Windows::Forms::PaintEventArgs^  e) {

        this->TransparencyKey = BackColor;   
    }
```

This doesn't work at all (The backcolor is still grey). So i have tried this:

```
private: System::Void button1_Paint(System::Object^  sender, 
System::Windows::Forms::PaintEventArgs^  e) {

        this->BackColor = System::Drawing::Color::Transparent;
    }
```

Here i got a message: This control doesn't support transparent colors

Ok, so how am i gonna do this?
thanks

Comment: Your code is C++/CLI not C++. Please tag your question appropriately.

Comment: c++ visual studio, windows application form

Comment: That doesn't make your code any less C++/CLI than it was a few minutes ago.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In WPF as well as win32, controls or child windows in general can't have color transparency.

But they can have a non rectangular region. Any shape, including holes.

Use the control's [region property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.region%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to change it's region. There's an example in this link on how to draw a round button.

FYI, pixels that are outside the region are NOT receiving any messages/notifications.

Examples of crazy shaped controls:

1. Button shaped like a person's head.
2. Spiral shape.
3. 3 triangles that do not touch each other.
4. Chess board - every 2nd pixel is transparent.

Also, a region is dynamic, can be changed after object creation, so your button can grow and shrink...

It's also pretty fast.

**Limitations:**

- No alpha blending - either opaque or fully transparent.

I wrote a function (C++/win32) that takes a control and a BMP, both have the same size, scan the BMP for a "tranparent" color (you decide which color) and remove all pixels in that color from the region of the control. This is about half a screen of code.

Comment: Can i also make a polygon - shaped button?  like those button on the top of the screen:                                          http://2.bp.blogspot.com/-B9JT0_HZH9g/UAeo6jeHtoI/AAAAAAAAAFI/U9wj_1JM1Ps/s1600/1+(5).png

Comment: By any shape, I meant ANY shape :). I'll add some xamples to the answer

Answer (score 1):

Set the `Background`-property to Transparent:

```
btn->Background = System::Drawing::Color::Transparent;
```

By the way, don't do this in the Paint-Handler. Instead, do it in the constructor or any initialization function.

**Update:**
Ok, got it - it's a Windows Forms application. See this [C# Windows Form Application Transparent button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10763640/c-sharp-windows-form-application-transparent-button) link for some solutions for your problem.

Another possibility (that I have used in projects before) would be to use a `PictureBox` instead and listen to the `MouseClick`-event.

Comment: It raises the same error: This control doesn't support transparent colors,   meaning button  (Tested in public Form1 function)