# Remove white border around a button

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a rectangle drawn in the background of my app window with this code :

```
public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    Paint += myDrawingPanel_Paint;
}


private void myDrawingPanel_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
{
    System.Drawing.SolidBrush myBrush = new System.Drawing.SolidBrush(System.Drawing.Color.FromArgb(0, 102, 205));
    System.Drawing.Graphics formGraphics;
    formGraphics = this.CreateGraphics();
    formGraphics.FillRectangle(myBrush, new Rectangle(0, 100, Form1.ActiveForm.Width, Form1.ActiveForm.Height));
    myBrush.Dispose();
    formGraphics.Dispose();
}
```

The buttons on this rectangle all have this white border around them and I'd like to remove them.
[image: Buttons with white borders] 
I tried to set the margins to 0, played with the appearance options but never managed to get rid of them.

Comment: Have you considered its the way the button draws not your panel?

Comment: I don't fully understand your question, do you want a transparent button? Try https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10763640/c-sharp-windows-form-application-transparent-button

Comment: @RezaAghaei It does what I needed, never thought about changing this. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Also the main problem in your code is because of `this.CreateGraphics()`. If you use `e.Graphics` you can not see the visual style artifact around the button.

Comment: Why are you calling `formGraphics = this.CreateGraphics();`?  Are you trying to draw on the form or on a panel?  In any case, you should not call `CreateGraphics`.  Instead, use the graphics instance that is passed into your Paint event handler.

Comment: @RezaAghaei Well it works, thank you. could you briefly explain me why ?