# A Transparent Button over A Windows Media Player element in C# WinForms

Tags: c#, winforms, button, video, transparent

I've been trying to have a hidden button over a Windows Media Player button but regardless of my attempts it always appears greyed out

```
axWindowsMediaPlayer1.Location = new Point(0, 0);
axWindowsMediaPlayer1.Size = new Size(Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Width, Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Height);
axWindowsMediaPlayer1.URL = "assets//vid//INTRO//INTRO_START.mp4";
axWindowsMediaPlayer1.Ctlcontrols.play();
axWindowsMediaPlayer1.uiMode = "none";
axWindowsMediaPlayer1.enableContextMenu = false;

startButton.Location = new Point(524, 741);
startButton.Size = new Size(1070, 236);
startButton.FlatStyle = FlatStyle.Flat;
startButton.BackColor = Color.Transparent;
startButton.FlatAppearance.BorderSize = 0;
startButton.Click += StartButton_Click;
this.Controls.Add(startButton);
startButton.BringToFront();
```

The output always appears to be the same where the button has a grey background

https://i.stack.imgur.com/SeaFU.jpg

Comment: I see no button at all. But: I don't think a transparent element is allowed to accept user interaction anyway; it would be a terrible UX, no?

Comment: Suggestion: try `startButton.FlatStyle = FlatStyle.Popup`

Answer (score 0):

set the background image, and image settings both to a blank png thats full alpha

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer using this class public class TransparentButton : Button

[C# Windows Form Application Transparent button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10763640/c-sharp-windows-form-application-transparent-button)

Answer (score 0):

Despite the common answers to this question, I don't think this is actually possible. At least for .NET Framework. First, from the [WinForms docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/winforms/controls/how-to-give-your-control-a-transparent-background?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8) (as outlined in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72938015/3697870)):

> Note: Windows Forms controls do not support true transparency. The
> background of a transparent Windows Forms control is painted by its
> parent.

So even if it were possible, you'd just see the parent's background colour (eg. black), not the contents of the media player.

However, from the same reference:

> Note: The Button control doesn't support a transparent backcolor even when
> the BackColor property is set to Transparent.

So buttons are out, which matches my experience. You may have better luck with custom painting.