# Triggering Button.PerformClick() on a hidden button

Tags: c#, winforms, button, contextmenu

I'm working on a C# WinForms application in which I have a number of processes that are all managed by a 'master' application.
In this master application, each process is visualized by its own `FlowLayoutPanel` which contains a number of buttons for various function. I call these panels the 'process blocks'.

However, when many of these processes are made, not all blocks easily fit on the screen. For this reason I am implementing a 'compact mode', which hides all the buttons of all the process blocks, leaving only their name, their status and the start/stop button visible. I then assign a `ContextMenuStrip` to each process block, in which I show all the buttons listed as a `ToolStripMenuItem` so I can access all the functions of the process block that way. I am clearing these `ContextMenuStrip`s dynamically and add the items when the menu is opened.
I do this by iterating over all the child controls of the `FlowLayoutPanel`, see if they are of type `Button`, and if so, I add them to the `ContextMenuStrip`. See the code snippet below:

```
private void PanelCmsOpened(object sender, EventArgs e) {
  try {
    ContextMenuStrip cMenuStrip = (ContextMenuStrip) sender;
    // Clear all items from the context menu
    cMenuStrip.Items.Clear();
    // Loop over all controls in the FlowLayoutPanel
    foreach (var c in CPanel.Controls) {
      Button btn = c as Button;
      if (btn == null) continue; // Not a button, continue
      // Get the text from the button
      string lbl = btn.Text;
      if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(lbl)) {
        try {
          // The button has no text (only an icon), so we get the tooltip text of the button
          lbl = PanelTooltip.GetToolTip(btn);
        }
        catch {
          // We can't get any text to display, so skip this button
          continue;
        }
      }
      // Add a new item to the ContextMenuStrip
      cMenuStrip.Items.Add(new ToolStripMenuItem(lbl,
                                                 btn.BackgroundImage,
                                                 (s, ea) => btn.PerformClick() // Perform a click on the button
                                                )
                                                {
                                                  Enabled = btn.Enabled
                                                });
    }
  }
  catch (Exception Ex) {
    MessageBox.Show("Fout bij openen van context menu: " + Ex.Message, "Fout", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
  }
}
```

The problem:
Now this is all working fine, as long as the buttons are visible. However, when going to compact mode, I hide the buttons by setting their `Button.Visible` property. In that case, nothing happens. I've tried putting a try-catch block around the `PerformClick`, but no exception is thrown. Just nothing happens. Does anyone know how to make this work for hidden buttons?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`PerformClick` checks if button available for clicking before performing click. Hidden buttons are considered unavailable. You can simply show button just before performing click, and hide it after clicking:

```
 cMenuStrip.Items.Add(
     new ToolStripMenuItem(lbl, btn.BackgroundImage, (s, ea) => {
          var size = btn.Size;
          btn.Size = Size.Empty; // button still will be invisible
          btn.Show(); // make it clickable
          btn.PerformClick();
          btn.Hide();  // hide again
          btn.Size = size; // restore original size
        });
```

NOTE: If you also need to add some visible buttons, then you should handle them separately to avoid flickering

```
 cMenuStrip.Items.Add(new ToolStripMenuItem(
      lbl, btn.BackgroundImage, (s, ea) => ClickButton(btn)));
```

Where `ClickButton` is a method which performs different logic depending whether button is visible or not:

```
private void ClickButton(Button button)
{
    if (button.Visible)
    {
        button.PerformClick();
        return;
    }

    var size = button.Size;
    button.Size = Size.Empty;
    button.Show();
    button.PerformClick();
    button.Hide();
    button.Size = size;
}
```

Comment: Thanks Sergey, this is exactly how I solved it using Atanas' help. Thanks for writing it out for us!

Answer (score 2):

The only thing you can't do is setting `visible = false;`

Other than that yu can use any trick to hide the buttons: You can stack them behind another control, you can move them out of sight in any direction or even move them into a different parent:

To hide them:

```
panel1.Size = Size.Empty;
button1.Parent = panel1;
//..
```

To show them again:

```
button1.Parent = this;
//..
```

Assuming they sit on the Form.

Note that they will have kept their original locations and sizes; watch for changes in the tab-order and z-order!

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion TaW. Because I use a FlowLayoutPanel, methods suchs as these are not very applicable to my case because the Panel takes care of positioning and padding etc.
However, this solution might be useful to others!

Comment: Ah, sorry, I overlooked that.

Answer (score 1):

If the button is not visible the Click event won't be raised. 
One option is to take the code which is in the button click event and add it as a separate method. Then call the method instead of the PerformClick row. This will work though if you do identical things on every button click.

Another options it to make the buttons transparent. This will make them invisible to the client and the PerformClick event will work fine. You can see that in the following link :[Drawing a transparent button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1086621/drawing-a-transparent-button).

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for your answer Atanas. The problem is that I am iterating over the buttons and as such, I don't know what code lies behind the Click functionality. I'm afraid making the button transparent will not do me any good, as it will not free up any space (the button is still there). You have given me a new idea through: I'm going to try to give the buttons a width of 0.

Comment: Another approach is to make them visible. Make a method which will be on the PerformClick row and will accept button as a parameter. Then you do the PerformClick on the button inside the method and hide the button after that.

Comment: This works. However, some buttons create a dialog, which means that the button stays visible until the dialog is closed. Maybe I can combine the methods of making them visible and temporarily setting their width to 0.

Comment: Yes, this works! Combining temporarily setting visibility to true and width to 0, the only glitch I see is a little bit of padding that is added to the panel. Good enough for me!
Atanas, if you can post your method as an answer I can accept it officially ;-)

Comment: I solved it in a similar way as Sergeys answer. Thanks for your help Atanas!