# how to set button opacity in windows forms

Tags: button, opacity

Is it somehow possible to give the button a opacity property like the form?

Because I want to make the button "invisible", but clickable.

Comment: a doubt : HOW TO CLICK AN _invisible_ BUTTON ?

Comment: Have a look at that: [Drawing transparent button](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1086621/drawing-a-transparent-button) It may be the answer to your question

Answer (score -1):

Although I'm not sure why you would want to do that, I think this might work:

```
<button class = "hide">My Button</button>
```

for the styling:

```
.hide{
  opacity: 0;
  background: none;
  border: none;
}
```

I am assuming this is html...