# How do I make a button invisible but still functional?

Tags: c#, winforms, button, calendar, invisible

I am currently trying to make a program where I have a picture of a calendar and when the user clicks on any given Friday a message box will appear. The current method I have been trying to do this is by placing a button over the dates, but I can't seem to find a way so that the button will be invisible and functional at the same time.

This is all in C# Windows Forms Application.

Any ideas?

Comment: Why don't you use the click event of the picture-control and use the x/y coordinates to check for a friday?

Comment: I am not sure what you trying to do but you can use a label instead without any text. Then use the `lable-click` event?

Comment: Why not use real controls instead of images?  It shouldn't be terribly difficult and it gives you a lot more flexibility.

Comment: You could use a transparent button:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1086621/drawing-a-transparent-button

Answer (score 1):

There are several solutions:

1. Use an empty `PictureBox` instead of a `Button`. This is the nearest and quickest solution to what you say you want. Note that this secondary `PictureBox` needs to be a child of the calendar's one (with its background color set to `Transparent`). Transparency in Windows.Forms only applies to direct parents (it's more complex than this, but let's simplify).
2. Use the `MouseUp` event on the `PictureBox` where you are showing the calendar, and use the `MouseEventArgs` supplied as arguments to the event handler to find the X and Y position of the mouse within that control when the button was clicked.
3. Use a decent calendar/datepicker control instead of showing an image of one

Matter of fact: I don't endorse #1, and just put it there since it's what you seem to be asking for. I'd rather go with #2 or #3 (specially #3)

PS: if you want to really simulate `Click`, you should need to handle both `MouseDown` and `MouseUp` (a click usually means pressing a mouse button down on a control then releasing it within the same control)

Comment: When using a picturebox it refuses to become transparent so that it doesn't have a square over my original picture, even if I set the back colour to transparent.

Comment: Add the picturebox as a child of the other picturebox (then set its background color to `Transparent`). Otherwise it'll "show-through" your control. There's no way around that for a PictureBox in WinForms (WinForms doesn't cascade opacity). I've edited to reflect this.

Comment: You could also make a different control which doesn't paint anything (like the transparent button linked on the comments), but I don't advise this solution (neither I do advise to use the empty `PictureBox` one, I was just putting it since it's the nearest solution to what you want to achieve)