# C# Visual Studio 2017 invisible + clickable buttons over a image

Tags: c#, winforms, button, visual-studio-2017

**Hey Guys** I have a little problem because I wanted to make a "search and get information" game, and I have the Image ready, but the buttons won't work, when I turn invisibility on.
I also read some simmilar questions on Stack Overflow, but the answers won't work for me! 
Because I'm new to coding, I would appreciate a "for beginners understandable" answer.

Thank You!

OfficialFreak

PS: Im working in Visual Studio 2017 and I'm making a Windows Forms App

PPS: heres a picture of how it looks[image: Horrible right?]

Comment: What are you setting to invisible? Buttons? Picture?

Comment: Im am setting buttons to invisible and then they're gone! (i cant use them)

Comment: Like expected ;) I think what you want is a button with an empty style instead of an invisible button

Comment: Exactly but how do i do this? and please post your awnser as a awnser

Comment: Here is a similiar question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1086621/drawing-a-transparent-button

Comment: and can i do this in the properties settings because i cant understand a single bit of the awnser!

Comment: Unfortunately it is not possible to do this in the properties. Very tricky in WinForms.

Comment: Then how... i cant just copy everything!

Comment: IIRC this is going to be nearly impossible using buttons.  Windows will generally translate a click of a transparent region into a click of the top-level thing behind it that is not 100% transparent.  This is because transparency is used to create non-rectangular controls and windows.  Instead, handle clicking on the picture and check for the position of the click to determine which action should be dispatched.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I got the answer by testing everything and voila:
You can make the buttons dissapear under the picture box by setting the picturebox to their parent here an example:

```
 btn_teeth.Parent = pictureBox2;
 btn_eye.Parent = pictureBox2;
 btn_eye1.Parent = pictureBox2;
```

After that you'll notice a border around the buttons.
You can remove that by going under "Flat Appearence" and turning border size to 0!

I'm not sure if that is everything because i set every color except for border of course to transparent and `UseVisualStyleBackColor` to False.
But that's all I know, and I hope that helps!