# Make a translucent button in VB.NET

Tags: .net, vb.net, winforms, visual-studio-2010

I want to make a translucent button in `VB.NET`. I know `Button1.backcolor = Color.Transparent` makes the background color of button totally transparent but I want it be translucent. What should I do to make it translucent or change the opacity of the button?

Comment: Use WPF instead of winforms.

Comment: @RBarryYoung is it available in Visual Studio 2010?

Comment: Yes WPF is available in vs2010.

Comment: Your answer can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1086621/drawing-a-transparent-button). Although that question's primary language is C#, the answers are the same. In particular, the top one: WinForms does not really support transparency.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use `Color.FromArgb` to make a control translucent. Let's say you have `Button1`  So the code will be

```
Button1.BackColor = Color.FromArgb(100, Color.White)
```

In place of 100, you can put any number between **1 to 255**. Change it accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Please check this msdn link that provides a method to set the opacity of windows form controls

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.color.fromargb(v=vs.110).aspx

```
controlName.backcolor = Color.FromArgb(alpha,red,gree,blue)
```

All four parameters (alpha,red,gree,blue) can have value between 0-255
While red, blue, green changes the color hue, the value of alpha changes the opacity. The higher the value, the more opaque the color. A value of 0 makes the color completely transparent